# How to pass a Set<List<Set<Integer>>> to hadoop map reduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I need to pass to map/reduce (hadoop implementation) a parameter of type

`Set<List<Set<Integer>>>`

For hadoop class JobConf i can use setInt, setFlot, setString, ecc but if i want to set "a set" or alternatively a list, is it possibile? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any way to do this through a "setter" method. 
However, you could write this Collection to a file and then add this file to the [Distributed Cache](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) and load it from the mapper's/ reducer's configuration.

Comment: I thinking the same thing (write on file and then read from file), but first i want to be sure that there not exist better ways.